# *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',

Tags: ios, selector

i am newbie to `iOS` and i want to implement a splash screen and load the data from database then transmit to another view controller to display data in a `UITableView`
here is my code

```
#import "SplashViewController.h"
#import "DataLoader.h"
#import "UISessionTable.h"
@interface SplashViewController ()  

@end
@implementation SplashViewController

@synthesize sessionsDataFromDatabase;





-(void) viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

   double  currentTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

    dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("session data loader", NULL);
    dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
        //code to load session into array

        self.sessionsDataFromDatabase = [DataLoader getSessions]; 
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{




            double differance = 5000.0 - ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] - currentTime) ;


            differance = differance<0? 0:differance;

            [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: differance target:self
                                                              selector: @selector(pushToSessionTableViewController:) userInfo: nil repeats: NO]fire];

                    });
    });
    dispatch_release(downloadQueue);


}
-(void) viewDidUnload{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.sessionsDataFromDatabase = nil;
}
-(void) pushToSessionTableViewController{


    UISessionTable * obj = [[UISessionTable alloc]init ];

    [obj setSessionsData:self.sessionsDataFromDatabase];


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];



}
@end
```

i got the following error when run

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'-[SplashViewController pushToSessionTableViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent 
to instance 0x6e45740'
```

any suggestion ???

Answer (score 2):

The colon at the end is for methods that receive parameters, yours doesn't receive anything. That's why it can't find the method (it assumes it is another undeclared method).

Replace

```
pushToSessionTableViewController:
```

with

```
pushToSessionTableViewController
```

Comment: Does it throw the same exception?